# Do you need a wiper blade for a crystal radio?

Tags: capacitor, radio

If you don't use a wiper blade, can you still adjust the received frequency if you have a variable capacitor?
Thanks

Comment: In designs that have a wiper, what is it used for?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie tapping an inductor at a variable point.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I know, the question was for OP.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a design that uses a variable capacitor: -

[image]

Picture from [this site](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/history/radio-receivers/crystal-radio-set-circuits.php).

And here's one that uses a wiper on the tuning coil: -

[image]

Picture from [this site](http://makearadio.com/crystal/13.php). And that slider design is based on [this kit](http://www.peeblesoriginals.com/catalog/45.php): -

[image]

And here's another with a wiper from [here](https://bizarrelabs.com/crystalradio2.htm): -

[image]